# Windows sits on the "Please Wait" screen for a long time during boot?

Tags: windows-7

I have a PC running a clean installation of Windows 7. I have noticed that Windows takes a very long time on the "Please Wait" screen during boot. I have cleared the startup list and also all of the startup items from Windows registry.

I have also tried several suggestions that I've found on internet like disabling the Network Locations awareness, etc, but nothing is improving the situation.

Of course in safe mode, everything works fine.

Event 100 details:

```
<Data Name="BootTsVersion">2</Data>
<Data Name="BootStartTime">2015-03-23T02:24:35.702800300Z</Data>
<Data Name="BootEndTime">2015-03-23T02:27:38.254320900Z</Data>
<Data Name="SystemBootInstance">107</Data>
<Data Name="UserBootInstance">106</Data>
<Data Name="BootTime">123699</Data>
<Data Name="MainPathBootTime">91799</Data>
<Data Name="BootKernelInitTime">24</Data>
<Data Name="BootDriverInitTime">10974</Data>
<Data Name="BootDevicesInitTime">191</Data>
<Data Name="BootPrefetchInitTime">34898</Data>
<Data Name="BootPrefetchBytes">248291328</Data>
<Data Name="BootAutoChkTime">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootSmssInitTime">20424</Data>
<Data Name="BootCriticalServicesInitTime">3107</Data>
<Data Name="BootUserProfileProcessingTime">41154</Data>
<Data Name="BootMachineProfileProcessingTime">1</Data>
<Data Name="BootExplorerInitTime">4843</Data>
<Data Name="BootNumStartupApps">1</Data>
<Data Name="BootPostBootTime">31900</Data>
<Data Name="BootIsRebootAfterInstall">false</Data>
<Data Name="BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootIsDegradation">false</Data>
<Data Name="BootIsStepDegradation">false</Data>
<Data Name="BootIsGradualDegradation">false</Data>
<Data Name="BootImprovementDelta">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootDegradationDelta">0</Data>
<Data Name="BootIsRootCauseIdentified">false</Data>
<Data Name="OSLoaderDuration">2653</Data>
<Data Name="BootPNPInitStartTimeMS">24</Data>
<Data Name="BootPNPInitDuration">485</Data>
<Data Name="OtherKernelInitDuration">1804</Data>
<Data Name="SystemPNPInitStartTimeMS">2262</Data>
<Data Name="SystemPNPInitDuration">10681</Data>
<Data Name="SessionInitStartTimeMS">12970</Data>
<Data Name="Session0InitDuration">1340</Data>
<Data Name="Session1InitDuration">712</Data>
<Data Name="SessionInitOtherDuration">18371</Data>
<Data Name="WinLogonStartTimeMS">33395</Data>
<Data Name="OtherLogonInitActivityDuration">12405</Data>
<Data Name="UserLogonWaitDuration">2932</Data>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What is "a very long time". What is your boot time in Event 100 of the Event Viewer. You find it when you drill down this chain : Eventvwr ==>
Applications and Service Logs > 
Microsoft > 
Windows > 
Diagnostics - performance > 
Operational > 
Event ID 100

Comment: Event 100 : 123699 ms. And this event has a exclamation red on the left. And Level: Error.

Comment: I have restarted windows several time , and all the times Event 100 is 120000-140000. and sometimes Leve :Error , sometimes Level: Critical.Always this event has Exclamation red on the left.

Comment: In events 101 etc it usually tells you which process takes all the time.

Comment: Al the other events are with yellow exclamation , and the level is Warning. But the sum of time on these events is lower than the value on event 100.

Comment: <Data Name="BootUserProfileProcessingTime">41154</Data> processing the userprofile is slow. Is this a large userprofile? Also capture a boot trace and share it: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: ( If this helps ) As you have noticed the time for user profile  I remember that 2-3 times , when I start my pc , after a very long time on "Please Wait" window , windows doesn't enter on desktop , but show the user name. I click and after I enter on desktop. ( The system has only one user , without password that logon automatically ). what does you mean with "large user profile " ?

Comment: capture the boot trace and share the compressed trace

Comment: have you captured the trace or are you no longer interested to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to Event 100 and click on the details tab (see pictures below). Then copy what you have there. It should look something like this:

```
    BootStartTime   2015-03-22T15:48:46.687200300Z
    BootEndTime 2015-03-22T15:51:15.516575500Z
    SystemBootInstance  1147
    UserBootInstance    1128
    BootTime    20690
    MainPathBootTime    9490
    BootKernelInitTime  19
    BootDriverInitTime  290
    BootDevicesInitTime 874
    BootPrefetchInitTime    0
    BootPrefetchBytes   0
    BootAutoChkTime 0
    BootSmssInitTime    5942
    BootCriticalServicesInitTime    334
    BootUserProfileProcessingTime   763
    BootMachineProfileProcessingTime    1
    BootExplorerInitTime    531
    BootNumStartupApps  9
    BootPostBootTime    11200
    BootIsRebootAfterInstall    false
    BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits    0
    BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits 0
    BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits    0
    BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits 0
    BootIsDegradation   false
    BootIsStepDegradation   false
    BootIsGradualDegradation    false
    BootImprovementDelta    0
    BootDegradationDelta    0
    BootIsRootCauseIdentified   false
    OSLoaderDuration    1882
    BootPNPInitStartTimeMS  19
    BootPNPInitDuration 898
    OtherKernelInitDuration 389
    SystemPNPInitStartTimeMS    1281
    SystemPNPInitDuration   266
    SessionInitStartTimeMS  1554
    Session0InitDuration    2547
    Session1InitDuration    281
    SessionInitOtherDuration    3113
    WinLogonStartTimeMS 7497
    OtherLogonInitActivityDuration  698
    UserLogonWaitDuration   176
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I updated my question , inserting Event 100 Details Data

Answer (score 0):

Possible bad sectors in your HDD if you have a fairly old one. If it's a faily new one, i'd try a memtest to see whether your RAM is causing any issues. Common cause for slow startups even on fresh installs can be the combination of both an old HDD and RAM or DIMM issue. Unless otherwise specified something going wrong with windows installation files if it's like you a said a fresh install.

Comment: I checked both HDD and RAM. Everything it's ok.

Comment: I think Shivam is right. Every process that involves the HDD seems to be very slow. There is no single outstanding process that is causing the delay - it is the sum of the processes. In safe mode nothing much is being loaded, thus the shorter loads. Can you move the system to another disk - preferably a SSD ??

Comment: Ok , but after this too long boot process , after windows and programs are working very fast. and as I noted before , I have checked the HDD with several tools but everything seems ok.

Comment: Tiku, can you create a new user profile,  make that your default, remove the other one, then test to see if it improves your loading... 

If you are still experiencing this issue that is.