# Black screen before login

Tags: windows-10

After booting into Windows 10 I see the Windows logo, and then a black screen for about 5 minutes before the login screen appears.

I can still move my mouse on the black screen. I tried removing all the programs from startup also.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: do the same xbootmgr command that I told you some time ago for Windows 7 /but this time use the Win10 WPT from the Win10 SDK:https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk): http://superuser.com/questions/892741/windows-7-takes-a-lots-of-time-on-please-wait-screen#comment1194178_892741

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when you have many applications in startup. Windows waits until those applications start and then it proceed for login.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open `Task manager` then navigate to `Startup` tab and disable the unwanted start up programs.

You can also control which services should run at startup.

To do that press <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> simultaneously and type `msconfig` in box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then go to `Services` tab. Then make sure that you check the box of `hide Microsoft services` so that you won't stop any OS service. And then uncheck the box of the services who don't need to run at startup. Then click on `apply` and hit `OK.` This settings take effect after restart.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn off "Fast Startup" mode (which is, in reality, a slow startup mode).
Steps here:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html

EDIT:

## Short Version

Look for Power Options => System Settings then at the bottom of the window there is an insert "Shudown settings" where you have to uncheck the "Turn on fast startup" option.

## How to Turn On or Off Fast Startup in Windows 10

1. Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click on the Power Options icon.
2. Click/tap on the Choose what the power buttons do link on the left side. (see screenshot 1 below)

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byIzv.jpg)

3. Click/tap on the Change settings that are currently unavailable link at the top. (see screenshot 2 below)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZM2o.jpg)

4. If prompted by UAC, click/tap on Yes.
5. Do step 6 or step 7 below for what you would like to do.
6. To Turn On Fast Startup

(This is the default setting) Under Shutdown settings, check the Turn on fast startup box, click/tap on the Save changes button, and go to step 8 below. (see screenshot 3 below step 8)

7. To Turn Off Fast Startup

Under Shutdown settings, uncheck the Turn on fast startup box, click/tap on the Save changes button, and go to step 8 below. (see screenshot below step 8)

8. You can now close the System Settings window if you like.

[screaanshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAq02.jpg)

If the Turn on fast startup setting is not listed, then you will need to close the System Settings window, enable hibernate, then start over at step 1 again.

## More info

The "Fast Startup" is a sort of hibernation mode, so if you power off your computer when lot's of programs are running / are open windows try to restore everything which involve lot's of read from your hard drive and can be long.

Comment: Done. I add that this solution worked for me, this is the reason why I share it. I just figure out that the question was posted in 2018 haha but anyway it might be useful to someone